# How can I predict the gross profit of drug sales in these types of big Pharma datasets?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics

Suppose my dataset is of the following design:

- Columns: Assumptions (Type of customers), Disease (What disease can the drug treat - one type), Location (a country), Value (the profit earned from the sale of a unit of this drug in that country, for that disease and assumption).

I thought of combining the Assumptions, Disease, and Location columns to form a single column, which can be interpreted as a unique variable.

Th objective is to predict the gross profit from the sales of the drugs in the listed countries. For e.g., my current thoughts are to define the variables as:

$$\text{Assumption}_i  + \text{Disease}_j + \text{Location}_k := x_{ijk}$$

such that $$x_{ijk} = \text{Value (profit obtained for combinations $i,j,k$)}$$

if there are $30$ different kinds of assumptions $(i=1,\dots, 30)$, $3$ types of diseases $(j=1,2,3)$, and $20$ different locations/countries $(k=1,\dots, 20)$.

I will then proceed with stepwise regression in the next steps.

Will this be an appropriate approach? If not, it will be great if some insight can be shared as to why it isn't, and also it will be great if someone will be able to share some common approaches to tackling similar datasets in predicting gross profits for the pharma industry.

Comment: I recommend that rather than asking "Will this be a good approach?" you select one aspect about which you have a question.  Otherwise asking for comment will be so open-ended that the question is likely to be closed as a poor fit for this site.

Comment: @rolando2 Thank you for the feedback. I will take it into consideration for future posts as well.